# How to write a hyper response body to a file?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, hyper

I am trying to write a test program with tokio that grabs a file from a website and writes the streamed response to a file. The hyper website shows an example that uses a while loop and uses the `.data()` method the response body, but I'd like to manipulate the stream with `.map()` and a couple others.

I thought the next reasonable thing to try would be to convert the stream to an `AsyncRead` by using the `.into_async_read()` method from `TryStreamExt`, but that doesn't seem to work. I had to use a map to convert the `hyper::error::Error` into a `std::error::Error` to get a `TryStream`, but now the compiler is telling me that `AsyncRead` isn't implemented for the transformed stream. Here is my main.rs file and the error:

```
use std::error::Error;

use futures::stream::{StreamExt, TryStreamExt};
use http::Request;
use hyper::{Body, Client};
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use tokio::fs::File;
use tokio::io;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let https = HttpsConnector::new();
    let client = Client::builder().build::<_, Body>(https);

    let request = Request::get("some file from the internet").body(Body::empty())?;
    let response = client.request(request).await?;

    let mut stream = response
        .body()
        .map(|result| result.map_err(|error| std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Error!")))
        .into_async_read();
    let mut file = File::create("output file").await?;

    io::copy(&mut stream, &mut file).await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `futures_util::stream::try_stream::into_async_read::IntoAsyncRead<futures_util::stream::stream::map::Map<hyper::body::body::Body, [closure@src/main.rs:20:14: 20:103]>>: tokio::io::async_read::AsyncRead` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:5
   |
24 |     io::copy(&mut stream, &mut file).await?;
   |     ^^^^^^^^ the trait `tokio::io::async_read::AsyncRead` is not implemented for `futures_util::stream::try_stream::into_async_read::IntoAsyncRead<futures_util::stream::stream::map::Map<hyper::body::body::Body, [closure@src/main.rs:20:14: 20:103]>>`
   | 
  ::: /Users/jackson/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-0.2.13/src/io/util/copy.rs:63:12
   |
63 |         R: AsyncRead + Unpin + ?Sized,
   |            --------- required by this bound in `tokio::io::util::copy::copy`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `futures_util::stream::try_stream::into_async_read::IntoAsyncRead<futures_util::stream::stream::map::Map<hyper::body::body::Body, [closure@src/main.rs:20:14: 20:103]>>: tokio::io::async_read::AsyncRead` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:5
   |
24 |     io::copy(&mut stream, &mut file).await?;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `tokio::io::async_read::AsyncRead` is not implemented for `futures_util::stream::try_stream::into_async_read::IntoAsyncRead<futures_util::stream::stream::map::Map<hyper::body::body::Body, [closure@src/main.rs:20:14: 20:103]>>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `core::future::future::Future` for `tokio::io::util::copy::Copy<'_, futures_util::stream::try_stream::into_async_read::IntoAsyncRead<futures_util::stream::stream::map::Map<hyper::body::body::Body, [closure@src/main.rs:20:14: 20:103]>>, tokio::fs::file::File>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it. You invoked `into_async_read` which gives you an implementation of [futures::io::AsyncRead](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.1/futures/io/trait.AsyncRead.html) but you want a [tokio::io::AsyncRead](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.9/tokio/io/trait.AsyncRead.html).

The [tokio-util](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-util) crate gives you a tool to do this conversion.

Add to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
tokio-util = { version = "0.3.1", features=["compat"] }
```

And say you add a conversion function like this:

```rust
fn to_tokio_async_read(r: impl futures::io::AsyncRead) -> impl tokio::io::AsyncRead {
    tokio_util::compat::FuturesAsyncReadCompatExt::compat(r)
}
```

then your code could become:

```rust
let mut futures_io_async_read = response
        .body()
        .map(|result| result.map_err(|error| std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Error!")))
        .into_async_read();

let tokio_async_read = to_tokio_async_read(futures_io_async_read)

let mut file = File::create("output file").await?;

io::copy(&mut tokio_async_read, &mut file).await?;
```

Comment: add 
tokio-util = { version = "0.3.1", features=["compat"] }
will worked,thank you

Comment: Does this still work with current versions of hyper? For me I can't call `into_async_read` (not found). (I do have the `use` for `TryStreamExt`.)

Comment: I had the same issue @robinst. You need to add the futures crate and import it (`use futures::{StreamExt, TryStreamExt};`)

Comment: This worked great until updating to hyper 1.0+

This is working for me now:

```http_body_util::{BodyExt, Collected}

...

let bytes = response.into_body.collect().await.map(Collected::to_bytes)```